# WifiManager's removeNetwork isn't' really removing wifi network

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I'm using removeNetwork in my application to remove a configured network. When I execute this method, everything acts as it should. The wifi disconnects and the SSID doe not appear in the list of configured netowrks... that is until i disable and re-enable the wifi radio. At this point, the SSID reappears and android automatically connects to the AP.

Does anybody know what's going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried calling the [SaveConfiguration()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#saveConfiguration%28%29) method after removing a network ?

According to documentation, you have to call it in order for the changes you've made to persist.

Hope this helps !

Comment: What permissions are needed for this to work? I tried it but I got a Permission error.